# Target Connection is Stale ERROR in WSO2 EI 6.4.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I'm trying to push incoming JSON payload to AWS SQS Queue in WSO2 EI 6.4.0. Facing Exception like `java.io.IOException: Target Connection is stale` intermittently.

We're unable to push payload to Queue.

Log:

```
    [2022-08-27 03:08:49,801] [-1] [] [HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-5]  WARN {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.Targe
tHandler} -  Connection closed by target host while sending the request  Remote Address : proxy.abc.com/
10.0.x.x:3090                                                                                                  
[2022-08-27 03:08:49,801] [-1234] [] [PassThroughMessageProcessor-29] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.P
assThroughHttpSSLSender} -  IO while building message                                                               
java.io.IOException: Target Connection is stale..
```

As per [this wso2 link](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Tuning+the+HTTP+Transport), do i need to disable this `http.connection.stalecheck` by making value as `1` in `<ESB_Home>/repository/conf/nhttp.properties` file?

Please suggest to resolve this issue.

Comment: How are you sending the message? Can you share the synapse configs?

Comment: Hi @ycr, By using connector, trying to push payload to queue. <amazonsqs.sendMessage> operation,  intermittently getting this error, same operation works for sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

The error `java.io.IOException: Target Connection is stale` is not the cause of your issue, it's just a by product of the actual issue. With the information provided I believe the actual issue is the following.

```
[2022-08-27 03:08:49,801] [-1] [] [HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-5]  WARN {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.Targe
tHandler} -  Connection closed by target host while sending the request  Remote Address : proxy.abc.com/
10.0.x.x:3090
```

Since the connection was closed by the target(Assume this is SQS) the collections are getting staled after some time. This is expected, so try to find out why the target is closing the connection. If you are going through a corporate Proxy, check the proxy first, then check SQS side to see whether there is any information useful to debug the issue.

Comment: Hi @ycr,
Thanks for information. There will be some corporate proxy through which request will be passed  from ESB and reached to destination. do you have any idea what kinda check needs to be done at proxy level? and also please let me know above shared link will be useful or not by disabling http.connection.stalecheck.

Comment: @Justin you can start by checking the logs of the proxy. The connection is closed by the target hence it should be closed by either the proxy or by SQS, so need to find out why. The `http.connection.stalecheck` is not relevant, so enabling/disabling it will not make a difference.